# How to put a variable for 'Title' of QInputDialog::getDouble?

Tags: c++, qt5

is it possible to print in the 'Title' of QInputDialog::getDouble a variable? I would like to insert after the word 'Rotazione ' the value of the variable int i of the 'for cicle'. I tryied 1) with simple 'i' and 2) with QString::number(i) but none works. The first) gives no error but the title is only 'rotazione' while the second) error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

```
void Byz::inserisciByz(Ui::Dialog *ui)
{
    bool ok;
    for(int i=0; i<=270; i+=90)
    {
        double dx = QInputDialog::getDouble(0, QObject::tr("Rotazione " + QString::number(i)),
                                        QObject::tr("delta x (mettere il segno - dove serve): "), 0, -100, 100, 2, &ok);
        if (ok)
        {
            ui->label_7->setText(QString::number(dx));
        } // end if

        double dy = QInputDialog::getDouble(0, QObject::tr("Rotazione" + QString::number(i)),
                                        QObject::tr("delta y (mettere il segno - dove serve): "), 0, -100, 100, 2, &ok);
        if (ok)
        {
            ui->label_7->setText(QString::number(dy));
        } // end if
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, this should work. Are you sure that the compiler error belongs to this version of the code? The call would better be `tr("Rotazione %1").arg(i)`, so you only have to translate `Rotazione` once, but this should still work. Did you maybe write `tr(i)`, this would explain the error "...conversion from int to const char*"?

Comment: `tr("Rotazione %1").arg(i)`  no matching function for call to 'QInputDialog::getDouble(int, QString)'
         double dx = QInputDialog::getDouble(0, QObject::tr("Rotazione %1").arg(i)), ----- Did you maybe write `tr(i)`? YES

Comment: `tr("Rotazione %1").arg(i)` worked now. I added one more ) `tr("Rotazione %1").arg(i))` and had the error. Also `QObject::tr("Rotazione ") + QString::number(i),` instead of what i wrote in the above code. Thank you very much